# Continuation of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a differential equation 
$$\dot{x} = f(x)$$
which has global solution for any initial value $x(0) \in \mathcal{S}$. Is there some theorem defining conditions under which this equation can be extended on closure of $\mathcal{S}$ and remain having global solutions for any initial value from closure?

Comment: it is unlikely. look at $\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2, x(0) = 1.$  the rhs $x^2$ is defined and bounded, yet the solution has a finite time blow up.

Comment: Do you assume (or require) the global solutions for various starting conditions to be _unique_?

Comment: @abel: but that equation _doesn't_ satisfy the assumptions in the question, unless $\mathcal S\subseteq\{0\}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, i see that it does not satisfy the hypothesis on global existence.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: Yes, both (assume and require)